# Recuperar un campo de un fichero JSON

Tags: java, json, jsonobject

¿Cómo puedo recuperar el título y los autores si están dentro de metadata y no es un array?

```
"metadata": {
        "title": "\"Multi-faceted\" COVID-19: Russian experience",
        "authors": []
}
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para completarla, agrega el código que estás intentando, lo que quieres hacer y qué errores o problemas tienes.

Comment: pueds acceder al title de esta forma `metadata.title`

Comment: @Enzo es Java, no Javascript.

Comment: Bienvenida, recuerda agregar lo que intentaste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.